# merge by similiartiy by string and part of string

Tags: r, string, merge

I have a dataframe (search) which contains sentences (in the orginal adresses), those adresses a formate quite bad. I have a additional dataframe (find) which contains single words (in the orginal cities), now I want to merge (result) such that, the Buzzword is searched in the A$search, and add therefore the ID. (The Results$Buzzword columns is nice, as controll, but not important). Thanks.

```
search <-data.frame(A = c("This is a  random example3   ", "This is even more radom test2", "Why would   text3 this happen", "how can toxt2 this", "complete difference"))

find <- data.frame(Buzzword = c("example3", "test2", "text3"), 
ID = c(1, 2, 3)

results <- data.frame(A = c("This is a random example3", "This is even more radom test2", "Why would  text3 this happen", "how can toxt2 this"), Buzzword = c("example3", "test2", "toxt2", NA), ID = c(1,2,2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the code below using `regmatch` + `match`

```
buzwd <- regmatches(
    search$A,
    gregexpr(paste0(find$Buzzword, collapse = "|"), search$A)
)

cbind(
    search,
    `row.names<-`(
        find[match(unlist(replace(buzwd, lengths(buzwd) == 0, NA)), find$Buzzword), ],
        NULL)
)
```

which gives

```
                              A Buzzword ID
1 This is a  random example3    example3  1
2 This is even more radom test2    test2  2
3 Why would   text3 this happen    text3  3
4            how can toxt2 this     <NA> NA
5           complete difference     <NA> NA
```

Comment: sorry for late reply I needed to test and tried to adjust.THe code above hepeld already a lot. Actually, the second step does not work in my context, as it stated (different Numbers of rows: ). I assume, that this ist, because in my first step, some of my strings finde several strings (for example in mx example row one "This" "" "example". Is this assumption right? is it possible to adjust, that maybe only the lasts string ist taken( when there are more matches). Thanks.